# Copy and paste form data using Inspect Element

Tags: google-chrome, inspect

I have a WebPage 'form' in Dev instance where an user can add rows and then manually insert data. I have the same webpage form deployed in another test server without any data in it.

In order to validate data in Test, I want the same DEV data (100's of rows) to be available in the Test Webpage form too. Database editing is not an option.

Is there a way that can be acheived through Inspect element or similar?

**Copy From WebPage1.html** - https://devsys.com/WebPage1.html

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

**Paste into WebPage1.html** - https://testsys.com/WebPage1.html

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

I tried inspect element in chrome where I can copy the element from DEV url but cannot paste the element in Test URL.